# Should you use call() when you call solidity functions from Javascript tests

Tags: solidity, javascript, testing, unittesting, test

Let's say my solidity code is

```
contract MetaCoin {

uint256 public balance = 0;

function getBalance() public view returns(uint) {
    return balance
   }

}
```

Let's say I want to call the getBalance function in my javascript tests; I have 2 ways to do it

```
const MetaCoin = artifacts.require("MetaCoin");
const metaCoinInstance = await MetaCoin.deployed();
// Way 1 using call
const metaCoinBalance = (await metaCoinInstance.getBalance.call()).toNumber();
// Way 2 without using call
const metaCoinBalance = (await metaCoinInstance.getBalance()).toNumber();
```

Which way is better and what's the difference between the 2 ways of calling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say it's mostly a preference, but I would go with the `.call(...)` version. The effect is exactly the same, but the `.call(...)` version clearly indicates to the reader that this is a constant method call that doesn't modify the state, where as you would use `.send(...)` for calling a non-constant method that does modify the state.